# Multithreaded HiLo game

Tags: java, game, multithreading, timer

For my CS class I have to write a HiLo game using multithreading.  I am brand new to multithreading and not sure how to best implement it.  The program below works, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.  When it is run the user will input an `int`, which is the amount of time that they will have to guess the correct number.  If the timer runs out the game will end.  I am not supposed to use the `Timer` object but instead use the `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Game implements Runnable {
    private static long time;
    private long timer;
    private static long gameTime;

    public Game(int n){
        gameTime=n;
    }

    public void run() {
        time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true){
            timer=(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000;
            if(timer>=gameTime){
                System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Hilo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length!=1){
            System.err.println("Must enter time");
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        int max=100;
        int min=1;
        int number=rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
        int gameTime=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Welcome to HiLo!");
        System.out.println("You have "+gameTime+" seconds to guess a number between 1 and 100.");
        Thread clock1 = new Thread(new Game(gameTime));
        clock1.start();

        while(clock1.isAlive()==true){
            System.out.println(">");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = sc.nextInt();

            if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input==number){
                System.out.println("You Win!");
                break;
            }else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input<number){
                System.out.println("Higher!");
            }else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input>number){
                System.out.println("Lower!");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Spacing

First of all, yourcodeispackedverytightly, try using spaces a bit more. This is preferred:

```
timer = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000;
int number = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

---

#### Static variables

```
private static long time;
private static long gameTime;
```

I see absolutely no need to have these as `static`. As it is right now, your code would get problematic if you instantiated one `Game`, waited for a while, and then created another game. Each `Game` should have it's own `time` and `gameTime` values.

---

#### Run and `while (true)`

```
public void run() {
    time=System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true){
        timer=(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000;
        if(timer>=gameTime){
            System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So here you have a repeating loop that does more or less absolutely nothing as fast as it can. As you already know how long you should wait, use `Thread.sleep(delay)` instead.

---

#### `==true`

```
while(clock1.isAlive()==true){
```

Using `==true` is redundant, simply this is enough:

```
while (clock1.isAlive()) {
```

---

#### Scanner resource

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This line should give you a compiler warning because you're not closing the scanner. Consider using a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

You only need to create the scanner once, when you start the program. Then you can close it safely at the end of your program.

---

#### if, if, if...

```
if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input==number){
    System.out.println("You Win!");
    break;
}else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input<number){
    System.out.println("Higher!");
}else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input>number){
    System.out.println("Lower!");
}
```

Do you see any common things there? `clock1.isAlive()` is being checked on every `if`. Sure, it is possible that it is alive in the first check and then dies before the second `if`, but that is very unlikely and we're talking about microseconds of difference there. Do the `clock1.isAlive` check once, and then check compare with the number.

```
if (clock1.isAlive()) {
    if (input == number) {
        System.out.println("You Win!");
        break;
    } else if(input < number) {
        System.out.println("Higher!");
    } else if(input > number) {
        System.out.println("Lower!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about closing the `Scanner` as it would close the underlying `System.in`, which you didn't allocate. I could imagine using  `System.in` later again, though it mayn't work as the scanner might have eaten some input in its buffer.

Comment: @maaartinus Correct. I just noted that the Scanner is created inside the loop, which is a bad idea. If it is created once on the start of the main method, then it can be closed safely at the end of the main method.

Comment: I missed that. Creating the `Scanner` inside of the loop is terribly wrong, as it can eat the data to be used for the next iteration. Closing or not, it's broken.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things I don't like:

- `time`, `timer` and `gameTime` defined as `static`. Why do you need that fields to be `static`? That's the recipe for a disaster if you ever need to create multiple instances of your `Game` class. And even if you just need one instance, please don't declare its member at `static`. Apart for some very specific cases (like when you define a constant value) you should avoid static variables.
- `Thread clock1 = new Thread(new Game(gameTime));` makes me think there is a bit of a confusion in the way you named your `Game` class. If it is effectively just a timer, why don't you simply call it `Timer`?
- I'd also change the names of the variables you used in your `Game` class. What about the following? Note that The class keeps track of `duration` with a field. The rest can be just local to the scope of `run`. And usually it is a good idea to give variables the smallest scope possible.

  ```
  class Timer implements Runnable {
      private final long duration;

      public Timer(long duration){
          this.duration = duration;
      }

      public void run() {
          long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + duration;
          while(true){
              if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= stopTime){
                  // I removed the I/O from here. Let's print the message in your main method
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- I'd refactor the `while` loop to check just once if the timer is alive. Have a look at the other comments I added in my code snippet

  ```
  bool isGameOver = false;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // You can reuse the same scanner.
  while(!isGameOver){
      System.out.println(">");

      int input = sc.nextInt();
      if(clock1.isAlive()){ // No need to have the == true part of the condition
          if(input == number){
              System.out.println("You Win!");
              isGameOver = true;
          }
          else if(input<number){
              System.out.println("Higher!");
          }
          else{ // No need to check that input > number here
              System.out.println("Lower!");
          }
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
          isGameOver = true;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

This is on top of the many good points others have already pointed out.

In particular, `Game` could be a lot cleaner:

- `gameTime` can be `final`: it never changes during the lifetime of a `Game`
- The constructor param `n` would be better named `gameTime`
- In the `run` method:

  - `time` would be better named `start`
  - `timer` would be better named `elapsedTime`
  - the variable storing elapsed time would be better declared inside the loop
- As Simon pointed out, your loop is a *busy loop*, which is not good, the CPU spinning and spinning evaluating the check for elapsed time very fast. You could `Thread.sleep(gameTime * 1000)`, but that might go against the instructions of your prof. In that case you can at least sleep for *some* time, for example 1 second or 100 milliseconds, which would be much better than a busy loop.

With these suggestions applied, the class becomes:

```
class Game implements Runnable {
    private final long gameTime;

    public Game(int gameTime) {
        this.gameTime = gameTime;
    }

    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            long elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000;
            if (elapsedTime >= gameTime) {
                System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // another thread has kindly asked your thread to exit
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I will quote [@Simon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-andr%C3%A9-forsberg)'s excellent comment about handling the `InterruptedException` in this example:

> If you get an InterruptedException from `Thread.sleep`, another thread has kindly asked your thread to exit. I think the proper response then is to break from the while-loop, which will end the method, which will end the thread.

Comment: Many good points here. However, if you get an `InterruptedException` from `Thread.sleep`, another thread has kindly asked your thread to exit. I think the proper response then is to break from the while-loop, which will end the method, which will end the thread.

Answer (score 2):

The other comments cover the code quite well, I have a few points to add.

First, obviously this is a critical error:

```
if (args.length!=1){
    System.err.println("Must enter time");
}
```

And yet you continue with your program knowing that it cannot possibly work. Either throw an exception (which will be reported to the user, and be ugly) or simply `return` to exit `main` and terminate the program:

```
if (args.length!=1){
    System.err.println("Must enter time");
    return;
}
```

This is a long and confusing way or writing your intent:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int max=100;
    int min=1;
    int number=rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
```

`min` and `max` should be compile time constants and be at the top of the class:

```
private static final int MIN_NUM = 1;
private static final int MAX_NUM = 100;
```

This way they are outside of the running code and clearly constants. Similarly `Random` should (almost) always by an instance or class variable as having more than one is (almost) never useful.

Use `printf` for outputting formatted messages:

```
System.out.printf("You have %s seconds to guess a number between 1 and 100.%n", gameTime);
```

This leads to fewer string concatenation problems and is easier to read.

Here is where the problems really start:

```
while(clock1.isAlive()==true){
    out.println(">");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = sc.nextInt();

    if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input==number){
        out.println("You Win!");
        break;
    }else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input<number){
        out.println("Higher!");
    }else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input>number){
        out.println("Lower!");
    }
}
```

1. never create a `Scanner` in a loop, and always close resources.
2. never write `if(boolean == true)` this is ugly and error prone (`if(boolean = true)` also compiles).
3. you only need to check `clock1.isAlive` once; after reading user input.

Lets tidy up these simple comments first:

```
try (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (true) {
        out.println(">");
        int input = sc.nextInt();

        if(!clock1.isAlive()) {
            break;
        }

        if (input == number) {
            out.println("You Win!");
            break;
        } else if (input < number) {
            out.println("Higher!");
        } else if (input > number) {
            out.println("Lower!");
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have a number of issues:

1. The `clock1` has no idea that we've won - it carries on and still emits that we lost.
2. `clock1` is a busy wait, so causes one CPU to "spin" while it's checking the time leaving it unavailable for anything else.

As `clock1` runs in a separate `Thread`, we need to consider visibility and atomicity of any variables used to communicate. So an `AtomicBoolean` seems the natural choice:

```
final AtomicBoolean gameOver = new AtomicBoolean(false);
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(gameTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
        gameOver.set(true);
    }
});
thread.start();
```

So we create a `AtomicBoolean gameOver` to communicate between the clock `Thread` and the main `Thread`. We place a sleep in the clock thread that sleeps for `gameTime` seconds, if the thread is interrupted before waking, it simply exits. This is much more efficient than your busy wait as it doesn't tie up an entire CPU core for absolutely no reason. **Never busy wait!**

We can now modify the game loop to:

```
try (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (true) {
        out.println(">");
        int input = sc.nextInt();

        if (gameOver.get()) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
            break;
        }

        if (input == number) {
            out.println("You Win!");
            thread.interrupt();
            break;
        } else if (input < number) {
            out.println("Higher!");
        } else if (input > number) {
            out.println("Lower!");
        }
    }
}
```

So we check whether the game is over after reading a new value from the user. In the winning condition we call `thread.interrupt()` which interrupts the clock thread and causes it to exit.

Comment: You point out some good things here but there are some things which is incorrect/bad: 1. The spec says that `Timer` should **not** be used. 2. I rarely see `import static` for System.out, I would not recommend that (although I can't really say there is anything explicitly wrong with it). 3. `sc.nextInt()` is a blocking operation, which is why a check needs to be done after that operation to make sure that the thread is *still* alive.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg all very good points - I seem to be being exceptionally slow today. Tried to address those points.

Comment: Much better, definitely worth an upvote.